# Codeigniter Reservation Module

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

So I am currently trying to develop a reservation module for our classroom project. I have a reservation table wherein I have a reservation ID, user ID, reservation date, and reservation time. My reservation time's values are '6', '7', '8', and '9' which points out the time reserved. In my check reservation status page, a user can see a date's status to whether what time has already been reserved. My problem is how do I output the reserved status properly?

For example: [image]

I have multiple records for 02/05/2017, and I used foreach loop. The problem is that if I used foreach, it will repeat the rows as shown below rather than showing only one row.
[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

Here's my code.

Controller:

```
function court_one()
{
    $data['date'] = date("Y/m/d");
    $data['result'] = $this->model_reservation_user->getcourtone_defaultavailability();
    $this->template->load('user_template', 'view_userreservation_courtone', $data);
}

function check_availability_courtone()
{
    $searchquery = $this->input->get('search', TRUE);

    if(isset($searchquery) and !empty($searchquery))
    {   
        $data['date'] = $searchquery;
        $data['result'] = $this->model_reservation_user->getcourtone_availability($searchquery);
        $this->template->load('user_template', 'view_userreservation_courtone', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('user_reservation/court_one');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
    function getcourtone_defaultavailability()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('courtone_reservation')->where('reservation_date', date("m/d/Y"))->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }

    function getcourtone_availability($searchquery)
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('courtone_reservation')->where('reservation_date', $searchquery)->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
      <table class="table table-hover">
              <tr>
                <th><br>Date and Time Reserved</th>
                <th><br>6:00-7:00</th>
                <th><br>7:00-8:00</th>
                <th><br>8:00-9:00</th>
                <th><br>9:00-10:00</th>
              </tr>

              <?php foreach ($result as $result): ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($date)); ?></td>
                <?php if($result == FALSE) { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } else if($result->reservation_time == 6) { echo '<td class="reserved"></td>'; } else { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } ?>
                 <?php if($result == FALSE) { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } else if($result->reservation_time == 7) { echo '<td class="reserved"></td>'; } else { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } ?>
                 <?php if($result == FALSE) { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } else if($result->reservation_time == 8) { echo '<td class="reserved"></td>'; }   else { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } ?>
                 <?php if($result == FALSE) { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; } else if($result->reservation_time == 9) { echo '<td class="reserved"></td>'; } else { echo '<td class="vacant"></td>'; }?>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: you can make an associate array with key as date and value as time in controller and loop it into view

Comment: can you provide an example how I would implement this in the controller? I'm fairly new to this that's why I have little knowledge I'm sorry

Comment: could you paste your controller function and $query->result(); result ?

Comment: I just added the controller function above. What do you mean by $query->result(); result?

Comment: output of $query->result();

Comment: Well, it takes all the records in the database that satisifies the query as seen in the model, and I can only retrieve it by using a foreach loop. However, I have no idea how to integrate an associative array with it in order not to repeat the rows

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you're only returning a single date with multiple hours in your results.

In your view...

```
// Start table row
<tr><td><?php echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($date)); ?></td>

<?php
// Set an array of 10 'hour' switches
$tdX = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

// loop through results setting the array switches
foreach ($result as $result)
  $tdX[$result->reservation_time] = 1;
}

// loop through array building row
for ($i = 6; $i<=9; $i++) {

 if ($tdX[$i] === 1 ) {
     $tdClass = 'reserved';
 } else {
     $tdClass = 'vacant';
 }

 echo "<td class='$tdClass'></td>";

}

// close row
echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your $query->result() output is as follow

```
  $array =  array(
         array(
             'reservation' => 7,
             'user_id' => 2011909,
             'reservation_date' => '2/05/2017',
             'reservation_time' => 6
         ),
         array(
             'reservation' => 8,
             'user_id' => 2011909,
             'reservation_date' => '2/05/2017',
             'reservation_time' => 7
         ),
         array(
             'reservation' => 9,
             'user_id' => 2011910,
             'reservation_date' => '2/05/2017',
             'reservation_time' => 8
         )
     );
```

In your controller make your data as associative array with date as follow

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $date = strtotime($value['reservation_date']);
     $reservation = $value['reservation'];
     $data[$date][$reservation] = true;         
 }
```

Pass your data to view and in view loop the data as follow

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
 <tr>
            <td><?php echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($key)); ?></td>
     if(isset($value[6]) && $value[6] ) { echo '<td class="reserved"></td>'; }else{} 
 }
```